# Instantiating an object by chaining constructors

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, polymorphism

My textbook has an example in the Files and Streams section that confuses me.

```
BufferedReader inFile = new BufferedReader (new FileReader ("data.txt"));
```

My thinking is we are creating an object, of type `BufferedReader` and constructing them with another classes constructor `FileReader` and then 'laying' that object into the `BufferedReader` constructor.

Why are we instantiating the object with two 'new' keywords and what is happening?

Does this fall under polymorphism or inheritism?

Comment: Please feel free to add how I should have asked this question more effectively.

Comment: I think your question is fine. You might be getting downvotes however because it's a very simple question (but that isn't really your fault).

Comment: Thank you for that clarification, I thought I did something wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this equivalent code will make more sense:

```
FileReader fileReader = new FileReader("data.txt");
BufferedReader inFile = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
```

All this does is construct a `FileReader` object that is used as an argument for the `BufferedReader` constructor. This is an example of neither polymorphism or inheritance, this is just nesting expressions inside other expressions.

Comment: That's so obvious now, thank you so much for the example. How common is nesting objects like such?

Comment: Chaining constructors is very common, especially with Readers and Writers

Comment: Thank you both, I will practice this today.

Answer (score 1):

Most stream classes can be chained together. The new operator returns an instance of the type following, using the constructor that follows. So the `FileReader` is initialized with a file that will be read, with the resulting object passed to a `BufferedReader` such that the read from the file will be buffered for efficient I/O during the actual read.